# jquery ui autocomplete - clears text with a mismatch after a match

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an issue with the autocomplete where when I type in invalid text that does not match from the start like aaaaaa, it remains. but when I type in something that matches to begin with like brown, it matches and shows a bunch of names that begin with last name brown. my DB has values like 
Brown, Scott
Brown, Peter

when I type Brown evrything shows up. when I dont type a space after Brown, and instead type Brown,S the text I type is cleared off. similarly when I type in Bro the list shows up. if I type Broa the list disappears and also the text Broa is cleard in the textbox.

How can I avoid this clearing of the text? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks